# When defining a new section command/macro, what is causing the \@startsection text to be repeated?

Tags: sectioning, latex-base

When I try producing a new section command `\orangesection`, which utilizes the LaTeX kernel command `\@startsection`, I end up with duplicated text. Where is it coming from? As a bonus, how could I track it down?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{orangesection}
\renewcommand\theorangesection{\@arabic\c@orangesection}
\newcommand\orangesection{\@startsection{orangesection}{1}{\z@}% 
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{orange}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\orangesection{Orange Section}
Here is a sentence to simulate a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the counterpart to `\sectionmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{orangesection}
\renewcommand\theorangesection{\@arabic\c@orangesection}
\newcommand\orangesection{\@startsection{orangesection}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{orange}}}
 \newcommand\orangesectionmark[1]{}                                  
 \newcommand*\l@orangesection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}                                  
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\orangesection{Orange Section}
Here is a sentence to simulate a paragraph.
\end{document}
```